# Free FTP Virtual Drive Software for Windows (if not on Linux)

Tags: ftp, online-storage

Is there something equivalent to [WebDrive](http://www.webdrive.com/products/webdrive/index.html) but free or open source ?

Update: I want on Windows if possible and be able to save a file on a virtual ftp drive from any software.
I know already I can type "ftp://user@some.ftp.server.com" into an Explorer address as suggested below but that doesn't transform it into a true virtual drive as i cannot save file from notepad for example.

Comment: What is it exactly what you want to do? That WebDrive has many features.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running Linux then there are a number of FUSE based filesystems (like SSHfs which makes SFTP/SCP access look like just another local directory structure).

Under recent Windows versions you can access plain FTP sites (even those requiring authentication) using Windows Explorer. For instance type "ftp://user@some.ftp.server.com" into an Explorer address bar or the start|run box and (after prompting for password) you will be able to use the resulting explorer window just as any other (complete with drag-and-drop file copying and moving).

Comment: I can access with Explorer, but it doesn't behave like a virtual drive : I cannot save a file from notepad directly as far as I remember.

Answer (score 0):

[Net drive](http://www.netdrive.net/) is Free for home use and available for windows.

> With NetDrive, managing your remote FTP and WebDAV servers will be as easy as any old file folders on your PC.
>
> Once you mount the local drive, you don't need to run an application or an FTP client interface but a simple drag-and-drop in your Windows Explorer will be sufficient to transfer and manage files.
>
> NetDrive v1.3 or greater uses neon, an HTTP and WebDAV client library.
>
> Neon is licensed under LGPL.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.